# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTML Document> has no method 'ready'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a simple javascript into a website (website is on weebly), and I'm getting this error.
In the resources tab on chrome I can see it's loading all of the scripts.
Here's a piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/cufon-yanone-250.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#coin-slider').coinslider();

});

</script>
```

That's all fitted on the bottom of the .html file. It's a coin slider gallery.

Anyone out to help me ?

---

*From comment...*

I am loading jQuery in the `<head>`...

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>`
```

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery from?

Comment: Yep, seems like you never load jQuery.

Comment: I am loading jQuery in the <head> ... <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Try to replace $ with jQuery to prove that jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Did replace $ with jQuery, the script is working now. Only problem is it melted the CSS (I guess), so I better get back to stylesheets. :)

Comment: what's the purpose of that semicolon after the script src?

Answer (score 4):

You specify no protocol in your `src`.

```
 <!----------v------->
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You at least need...

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/...
```

otherwise...

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/...
```

Comment: Unless he has a subfolder `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/` on his server - but ok, I think the chances of winning the lottery are higher ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Fair point... and I'll give you 10-1 odds. `;)`

Comment: from user comments it seems first a conflict problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that object `$` is not a jQuery object but another function that return the DOM object directly. So, probably you have another library that conflict with jQuery.

From doc of jquery you can solve it with [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

EDIT from question edit:

you must specify protocol in your jquery include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

without semicolon after `src` value